# Is it ok to use 'Empire' twice in a sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I went through this [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Costa_Rica) when I read the following sentence:

> It remained a peripheral colony of the **empire** until independence as part of the short-lived First Mexican **Empire**, followed by membership in the United Provinces of Central America, from which it formally declared sovereignty in 1847.

Now, my questions are:

1. Do they talk about the British Empire while using 'empire'? Here, if it is not directly told, then what's the need to write it, and that too in small letters? Is it necessary to write?
2. Is it ok to remove one 'Empire' in the following way:
   It remained a peripheral colony until independence as part of the short-lived First Mexican Empire,...

Thank you for your help. 
Can the sentence change the meaning?

Comment: (EDITED) Sorry just read the source. It's a bit ambiguous actually, at least without knowing more about the subject they're discussing. I'd also ask, 'what empire?'. But regardless in this context it's a noun, not a proper noun, so no capitalisation is required. If they are talking about the British Empire then you could alter it to read "It remained a peripheral colony of the British Empire…". But your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: Can we write the sentence without mentioning 'empire' then?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence before the one you post is

> Costa Rica was sparsely inhabited by indigenous people before coming under Spanish rule in the 16th century.

Now to answer your questions

1 The "empire" is a common noun. It does not need to start with a capital letter. It refers to the Spanish Empire (which is the *name* of an empire). We are supposed to equate "Spanish rule" with the Spanish Empire. Obviously you didn't do this.

Some readers may also know that the First Mexican Empire is the name used to talk about Mexico in the early days of its attempt to gain permanent independence from (the empire of) Spain. This may help to make the mental leap from "the empire"to "Spanish rule" = "Spanish Empire." Overall, for an "encyclopedia" entry, I think it requires its readers to make too many mental leaps (it assumes too much knowledge on the part of the reader).

2 If you take out "of the empire" from the sentence, we immediately ask "a peripheral colony of what?" The use "of *the* empire" (note the direct article) tells us it is of an empire that the writer expects to know about, and this is why we are meant to equate "the empire" with the previously-mentioned "Spanish rule." This is probably why the sentence uses the word "E/empire" twice, and it is "okay" to do so.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, the **empire** is referring to the Spanish Empire, but to the same extent as if it was referring to the British one. It is not capitalized because it is referring to the empire not as if it was explicitly the Spanish Empire, but rather, to the empire the Mexico was a colony of. It is saying the empire that Mexico belonged to, which happened to be the Spanish Empire. In that sense; since it's not a proper noun by itself it need not be capitalized, and since the "Mexican **Empire**" is proper, it is capitalized.

As for your second question, you can write it without the first **empire**, since the sentence still has the same meaning: Mexico was a colony at one point, but then it became independent. It is just saying the same thing with fewer details.

And, lastly, for the question in the title, it is perfectly fine to use the word **empire** twice in a sentence, especially since the two empires mentioned are different empires, not the same ones, so it is not redundant.

Answer (score 0):

In general, avoid using the same word twice in one sentence.  It sounds awkward to repeat words. Exceptions include short, common words like "he" and "the", and cases where you are deliberately making a parallel. This is not an absolute rule but simply a guideline. If eliminating the duplication makes the sentence difficult to understand, live with it. But none of those exceptions apply here.

There is an added problem with this sentence that the word "empire" is being used to refer to two different empires, but this is not clearly spelled out.

The common solution to this problem is to reword it to use some alternative to the word you were tempted to repeat. In this case, I'd be inclined to write something like, "It remained a peripheral colony **of Spain** until independence as part of the short-lived First Mexican Empire, followed by membership in the United Provinces of Central America, from which it formally declared sovereignty in 1847."

RE capitalization: Many words can be used as both part of a proper noun and as a common noun. The word is capitalized when used as part of a proper noun, and is not capitalized when used as a common noun. In this case, the "Spanish Empire" versus "an empire". That said, sometimes a generic word is used as a proper noun and capitalized. For example, when I was growing up near New York City, people in the region routinely referred to it simply as "the City". The Hebrew Bible routinely refers to the Mediterranean Sea as simply "the Sea" and the Euphrates River as "the River", and in English Bibles they are capitalized like I just wrote them.

And note I repeated the word "capitalized" many times in the above paragraph, and I don't think I made it particularly awkward.

Comment: "There is an added problem with this sentence that the word 'empire' is being used to refer to two different empires, but this is not clearly spelled out" is an important point.